# How can I make Chrome allow access to a webcam over http (not https)?

Tags: google-chrome, webcam, webrtc, kiosk-mode

I am building a kiosk application using webrtc video. It is only served on the internal network and I would like to be able to always allow the webcam for my site over http. Using ssl isn't that important and is just an extra expense for a cert.

Is there any way to do this or am I stuck?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, an admin can override the prompts with a policy.

[VideoCaptureAllowedUrls](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=VideoCaptureAllowedUrls)

> Patterns in this list will be matched against the security origin of the requesting URL. If a match is found, access to audio capture devices will be granted without prompt. NOTE: This policy is currently only supported when running in Kiosk mode.

On Windows, you create registry entries using regedit.

```
Software\Policies\Chromium\VideoCaptureAllowedUrls\1 = "http://www.example.com/"
Software\Policies\Chromium\VideoCaptureAllowedUrls\2 = "http://[*.]example.edu/"
```

On Linux you write the policies in a file:

```
mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed
touch /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/test_policy.json
```

In test_policy.json:

```
{
  "VideoCaptureAllowedUrls": ["http://www.example.com/", "http://[*.]example.edu/"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, I am back on the project and feel stupid asking this, but don't do registry much.  I tried setting it a few different ways in regedit and can't make it work.  I'm sure I just did it wrong, but its not really documented well either.  I am using the latest google chrome in kiosk mode.  What would the actual keys and structure look like in there and what type of key should I be using?

Comment: I am unable to try this right now, but I believe that you are supposed to create a key structure Software\Policies\Chromium\VideoCaptureAllowedUrls and inside that "folder", you create a new string value with the name "1" and value "http://domain.to.allow.com".

Comment: Is this in HKEY_CURRENT_USER? Tried both there and in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: I'm on linux with chromium 41 and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 10):

**Use command-line flag**

use `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` command-line flag

example (OS X) : `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/record-user-webm.html --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream`

More info here http://creativcoders.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/chrome-always-allow-access-to-webcam-and-microphone-over-http-webrtc/

Comment: Doesn't work in (at least) Chromium 72; "unsupported command-line flag" :-(

Answer (score 5):

More detailed solution.

In command line, target your browser and add after your instruction the --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream flag, like this:

```
//On windows

#Normal mode
start chrome "http://localhost" --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream

#Kiosk mode (full screen)
start chrome --kiosk "http://localhost" --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

For Linux and Mac command line instructions, see this: https://creativcoders.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/chrome-always-allow-access-to-webcam-and-microphone-over-http-webrtc/

Answer (score -5):

1. Right-click the webcam capturer
2. If you already allow just tick "remember"

Comment: I think Chrome doesn't allow you to remember that setting in localhost and over http (not https).