# Can I make the "Allow website to use camera" button in Chrome less subtle?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webcam

[image: chrome banner thingie]

This dialog is too subtle for some of my users (heck, I miss it myself sometimes).  Is there a good way that I can force it to be more obvious in order to avoid support calls?

Edit: I know about the trick of using arrows or pictures to draw attention to the banner, but I'm wanting something less ugly.

Comment: You could make an warning on your site with an image and arrows?

Comment: FYI in Chrome 41 the camera permission UI will change, you can try and see how it looks with `--enable-permissions-bubbles` (there are a few bugs at the moment, in Chrome 38 I had to open a new tab then go back to the original tab to see the UI if I called getUserMedia from the console.)

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a good way that I can force it to be more obvious in order to avoid support calls?

No. But what you *can* do is have directions on your website that might even have a picture of the various "Allow" banners/buttons offered by various browsers and call attention to what the user should look for, perhaps esp. the first time they use the feature.

E.g., a (much) better version of this:

[image]

Comment: I know about this, but I was wanting something more.  I edited my question

Comment: @thepaulpage: The answer is still "no," I'm afraid. You can't control that aspect of the UI of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to achieve what you want.

I can imagine two workarounds:

- instruct the user what to do (like T.J. Crowder has already stated)
- In case you control the clients using your webapp: [Set a browser-policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069979/chrome-always-allow-webcam-over-http). Then no prompt would appear.