# How do I get protractor to accept the browser local camera

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, testing, selenium, protractor

I've been trying to get protractor to accept the browser local camera by using

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB, protractor.Key.TAB, protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

This tabs to the accept button properly, but the enter key never gets submitted. I've also tried using

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB, protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

thinking that maybe enter needed to be on it's own line.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to manipulate the question popup using `switchTo()`, but I am afraid this is not going to work since this is a native chrome popup and not a javascript alert:

```
 browser.driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Here are the options (not tested yet):

- start chrome with [`disable-web-security` argument](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-web-security) set in [`chromeOptions`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#adding-chrome-specific-options):

  ```
  chromeOptions: {
      args: [
          'disable-web-security'
      ]
  }
  ```
- start chrome with [`use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` argument](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-fake-device-for-media-stream):

  ```
  chromeOptions: {
      args: [
          'use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'
      ]
  }
  ```
- add your site to the [`VideoCaptureAllowedUrls` list](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#VideoCaptureAllowedUrls) (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070163/771848))

  ```
  chromeOptions: {
      prefs: {
          'VideoCaptureAllowedUrls': ['http://my_url']    
      }
  }
  ```

---

Also, have you tried pressing `TAB` 3 times?

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB, protractor.Key.TAB, protractor.Key.TAB, protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of these solutions have worked for me. The strange thing is that I can see that pressing TAB twice activates the correct tab button, but ENTER isn't doing anything.

Comment: @pedalpete that's ok, let see what other options there are. Can you share a link where this question popup shows up so I can debug it? Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to use a combination of `videoCaptureAllowedUrls` and args, but apparently the allowedUrls was breaking the args. Removing that and just using `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` worked in the end. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently you now need to exclude the `--` of the arguments. `-–use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` didn't work for me but `use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` did work.

Comment: @wwv yeah, I'm actually using it without the `--` :) Thank you for noticing!

Comment: Hi there! So what is the final solution here, it is marked with a green tick, but none of your comments is working for me. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
     args: ['--use-fake-device-for-media-stream','--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'],
    }
  },
```