# Internet Exlporer - how to always grant the page access to webcam

Tags: internet-explorer, group-policy

I'm creating application which uses WebRTC. Application is some kind of videoconference which displays site in fullscreen mode. Is it possible to grant the page automatic access to webcam and microphone? Of course I don't want to made users to do it. I've got IE 11.
I saw some sollutions for Chrome:
[Chrome always allow webcam over http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069979/chrome-always-allow-webcam-over-http/17070163#17070163)

I can't find anything simillar for IE. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the group policy settings for IE? This is an administration question, not a programming question and unrelated to WebRTC

Answer (score 0):

IE is yet to support WebRTC:

https://status.modern.ie/webrtcwebrtcv10api?term=webrtc

While a WebRTC prototype was developed back then with IE10, they stopped supporting it:

http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/

Apparently, Microsoft is now trying to come up with a different protocol similar to WebRTC:

http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/object-rtc/object-rtc/info

Answer (score 0):

On IE you just need to to this link:
https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html
[image]

1. From the list of Visited Websites, locate `yourdomain` and click the Always allow radio button.
2. Close all Internet Explorer windows to save changes.

[Solution provided by agsci.psu.edu](http://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/allow-camera-and-microphone-access-in-adobe-connect-breeze)